# How to dispose delegate in blazor or c#

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, blazor, delegates

Below I have attached my blazor code.

```
private delegate Task keyActionDelegate(KeyboardEventArgs e);
private KeyActionDelegate _keyActionDelegate;

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    _keyActionDelegate = new KeyActionDelegate(keyActionHandler);
    Attributes = BaseUtils.UpdateDictionary("onkeydown", _keyActionDelegate, Attributes);
}

internal async override void ComponentDispose()
{
    base.ComponentDispose();
    _keyActionDelegate = null;
}
```

A memory leak has occurred due to **keyActionDelegate**.

I have tried setting the null value to the **_keyActionDelegate** variable in the **ComponentDispose()** method, but still a memory leak has occurred. Is there any other way to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Alamakanambra, A memory leak has occurred due to keyActionDelegate, so I am trying to dispose of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    _keyActionDelegate = keyActionHandler;  // shorter syntax

    // this is the leak
    Attributes = BaseUtils.UpdateDictionary("onkeydown", _keyActionDelegate, Attributes);
}

internal async override void ComponentDispose()
{
    base.ComponentDispose();
    _keyActionDelegate = null;  // doesn't help
   
    // you need something like this
    BaseUtils.RemoveFromDictionary("onkeydown", _keyActionDelegate);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Henk Holterman, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this approach by removing onkeydown on dispose. `Attributes.Remove("onkeydown");` but still a memory leak occurs.

Comment: Well, nothing much I can see from here. Maybe post the code for BaseUtils.UpdateDictionary .  And tell us which rendermode is used. Best is always a [mre]